# is epoll (epoll_wait, etc.) available for iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, epoll

I'm just embarking on porting some existing POSIX compliant code to iOS.  From what I gather pthreads are available (good), but the compiler is not finding .  Is epoll available for iOS?

Answer (score 4):

No. `epoll` is a Linux-specific system call.

The closest equivalent on the Darwin kernel is `kqueue`, but I strongly suspect that's considered SPI (and hence off-limits) on iOS.

Comment: `kqueue` works fine on iOS and is mentioned in [some of their developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFileDescriptorRef/Reference/reference.html).  Grand Central Dispatch provides the Apple-blessed interface for async io.

Comment: SPI? What sense of SPI are you using in this answer?

Comment: @ wulong Have you ever compile the code in the link into an iOS App and test it on any iDevices?