# iOS problems using c++ code which invoke epoll()

Tags: c++, ios

I knew that iOS apps could use shared C++ library. However, now I have some C++ code that uses epoll() function, and iOS is based on a BSD kernel that doesn't have epoll() function, so when I integrate these C++ code to my iOS xcode project, there are some compile error, such as "sys/epoll.h file not found" and so on.

How could I do now? Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327275/is-epoll-epoll-wait-etc-available-for-ios

Comment: @MrMojoRisin you mean I should rewrite the part of c++ code and use kqueue() to implement the same function which was implemented by using epoll()?

Comment: If poll() isn't available on iOS, you haven't the choice :/

Comment: @MrMojoRisin poll() is available on iOS, but epoll() isn't. I'm afraid that if I use poll() to replace epoll(), it could result in less performance in handling I/O events